# Clause relation, grammar

Tags: grammar, clauses

*Let us work together in providing the **poor quality** and affordable healthcare.*

In the above sentence, how it can be determined whether the word 'poor' is used as adverb for quality or it refers to people. In each case, the sentence has two different meanings.

Comment: By common sense and by the knowledge that *the poor* is a known and common term to refer to *the poor people*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are under the impression that this sentence can be parsed as

> Let us work together to provide poor quality, affordable healthcare.

But it cannot. Leaving aside the absurdity of someone encouraging the provision of some yet unknown quantity — we haven't read to the end yet — in poor quality, the noun phrase *the poor quality healthcare* would require an essential (restrictive) clause, such as

> the poor quality healthcare to be expected from such a mediocre clinic.

The use of the definite article would signal an essential clause as unambiguously as:

> Now that's the Beyoncé we know and love!

That such a phrase isn't forthcoming is a cue to reparse the sentence, reading *the poor* as an indirect object.